# Inline images not working with Play Framework 2.1

Tags: java, html, image, playframework

I am trying to render image thru BufferedArray using Play Framework. The images are not being rendered with any of the following approaches. Any pointers are really helpful

1. Returned **byte[]** from Bean and rendered in **main.scala using @bean.property**. I can see the data coming by viewing source.
2. Wrote the image to temporary location and using the URL returned in " > tag. No success.
3. Used inline image approach (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (with and without Base64 encoding and image file size less than 32KB) but still no luck.

Any help/pointers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Play!Framework 2.1.0**. Let, the image is located at `D:\\Images\\juventus.jpg` (I am **Windows** user). Below is the solution for your problem :

```
public static Result showImage() {
    try {
        byte[] array = Files.toByteArray(new File("D:\\Images\\juventus.jpg"));
        return ok(array); // render image
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.error("An IO Exception is occured while reading file!");
    }
    return internalServerError("An IO Exception is occured while reading file!");
}
```

That should render the image as a response. May this post is useful.. ;)